# PHP Using $_GET without a variable defined in URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

If I have a directory called "dir" with a file called "index.php", is it possible to handle a string in the URL without any variable specifically defined within the url?

Eg. If the user types http://domain.com/dir/hello.world

Is it possible to handle that 'hello.world' from dir/index.php without it being assumed as a file that does not exist?

I'm assuming this is a htaccess thing, I know how to make variables hidden in a url with htaccess (so like `/index.php?var=something` becomes `/var/something`) but I don't know how I'd go about doing it so it becomes just `/something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to implement something often referred to as "pretty urls".  You can do this by forcing all requests that aren't files or directories to the index.php in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Then you can pull your parameters out of the request uri:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it's good. Though one thing I changed was using these rules: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?var=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]` so everything is passed to `var` variable. Though your solution is better when there's more than one variable being passed.